# Im having trouble with changing/updating global variables in python

Tags: python, global-variables

So I was having trouble understanding the basics of global variable as I am a beginner in python. I wanted to try to change a global variable but unfortunate it didn't work. Could any of you explain and help my fix my problem. Thanks!!

```
global x
x = 10
def NEWX():
     print (x)
     x = x + 5
     print (x)
print (x)
NEWX()
print(x)

#this displays 10 10 15 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this refactor:

```
x = 10


def new_x():
    global x
    print(x)
    x = x + 5
    print (x)


print(x)
new_x()
print(x)

# prints 10 10 15 15
```

I was unable to run your original code, it complained about `x` being undefined in the function. Within the scope of the function, `x` is unknown. It's known at the higher scope, but not in your function. That's why the `global x` statement needs to be in the function - to let python know to use the `x` from the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 10

def NEWX():
     global x
     print (x)
     x = x + 5
     print (x)

print (x)
NEWX()
print(x)
```

Global variable rules:

- *global* keyword outside a function has no effect
- Variable outside a function is global by default
- *global* keyword is needed to read and write global variable within a function

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are first printing the value of x. The function `NEWX():` is then called which prints x, then adds 5 onto x and prints the new value. After the function is called, x is printed again.

To understand what is happening, check out this example that contains the fix:

```
 x = 10

def NEWX():
    print (x)
    global x
    x = x + 5
    print (x)
print (x)
NEWX()
print(x)
```

[image]